# Web scraping from dynamic websites in Python and Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, dynamic

I asked a question yesterday and got an answer from @QHarr that dynamic websites like Workday (take https://wd1.myworkdaysite.com/recruiting/upenn/careers-at-penn for example) generate job posts' links by making extra XHR requests. So, if I want to extract specific job post links, the normal webpage **scraping** using HTML parse or CSS selector by keywords is not feasible while the links cannot be extracted from the HTML source code generated by the Selenium driver. (Based on WeiZhang2017's GitHub post: https://gist.github.com/Weizhang2017/0029b2ff59e943ca9f024c117fbdf88a)

In my case, websites like Workday using Ajax to load data while needed, I used Selenium to simulate page scroll down and get more data as needed. However, as for getting the JSON response using Selenium, I searched a lot but couldn't find an answer that fits my need.

My thought to extract specific job posts' links was by 3 steps in general:

1. Use Selenium to load and scroll down the website
2. Use a similar method like request .get().json() in Selenium to get the scrolled down website's JSON response data
3. Search through the JSON response data with my specific keywords to get the specific posts' links.

However, here comes my questions.

**Step1:** I did this by a loop to scroll down pages I want. No problem.

```
scroll = 3
while scroll:
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)")
    time.sleep(3)
    scroll = scroll -1
```

**Step2: I don't know what kind of method can work after searching a lot and couldn't find an easy-to-understand answer. (I am new to Python and Selenium, limited understanding of dynamic websites *scraping* )**

**Step3:** I think I could handle the search and get what I want (specific job posts' links) once got the JSON data (assumed it named log) as shown on the Chrome Inspect-Network-Preview.

```
list = ['https://wd1.myworkdaysite.com' + x['title']['commonlink'] for x in log['body']['children'][0]['children'][0]['listItems'] if x['instance'][0]['text']==mySpecificWords]
```

Appreciate any thoughts on the step2 solutions.

Comment: When you  say, "Use a similar method like request .get() in Selenium to get the scrolled down JSON response data" do you mean, get the HTML that is now loaded onto the page?

Comment: my mistake, it should be the JSON response, should be the request.get().json()

Comment: I think, it's one of the most beautiful question. Almost 98% websites like this type of websites  transport their  data using backend as json format., in rare case if not then we need to use selenium to scrape the site.

Comment: @Fazlul I guess your mean is better to use the request.get().json() to retrieve the JSON data instead of using Selenium? As for the page scroll down and get more data, there could be another method to do that. Am I right?

Comment: Actually, this type of website is very easy to scrape  using scrapy when send json data as api calls/backdoor/backend .

Comment: @Fazlul Thanks for the hint! I'll look into it.